# Pipeline for Vector Manipulations in R as Replacement of dplyr data.frame Manipulations

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, pipeline

There is a common well known `dplyr` pipeline manipulating with a character column in a data frame:

```
library("dplyr")
data.frame(someVector = c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc")) %>% 
  distinct(someVector) %>% 
  arrange(someVector) %>% 
  filter(someVector != "bbb") %>% 
  pull(someVector)
```

This pipeline returns the desired vector result:

```
[1] "aaa" "ccc" "ddd" "fff"
```

However the cast of character vector to dataframe and back seems to be not optimal. Using the same sequence of functions with the vector as the parameter

```
c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc") %>% 
   distinct() %>%
   arrange() %>% 
   filter(.data != "bbb")
```

causes errors:

```
c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc") %>% distinct() 
Error in UseMethod("distinct") : 
  no applicable method for 'distinct' applied to an object of class "character"
   
c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc") %>% arrange() 
Error in UseMethod("arrange") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange' applied to an object of class "character"
 
c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc") %>% filter(.data != "bbb")
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"
```

That is why the used functions need to be "translated" into (replaced with) their vector analogues:

```
c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc") %>%
  unique() %>% 
  sort()
```

I do not know the equivalent of `filter()` for vector manipulation in a pipeline way. The question is how to make a proper (most optimal "R - style") pipeline vector manipulation for the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options. For example,

this

```
c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc") %>% unique() %>% `[`(. != "bbb") %>% sort()
```

this

```
c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc") %>% unique() %>% .[. != "bbb"] %>% sort()
```

and this

```
c("fff", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc") %>% unique() %>% magrittr::extract(. != "bbb") %>% sort()
```

all give

```
[1] "aaa" "ccc" "ddd" "fff"
```